# App crashes when taking photos quickly

Tags: android, android-camera

In my app I have a button that takes a photograph and saves it. The preview is not displayed.

The app works fine if i click the button every 1-2s but if I click it faster the app crashes. I am able to take all the photos I want as long as I don't click the button too fast.

PhotoFragment.java:

```
public class PhotoFragment extends Fragment {
    private final static String LOG_TAG = PhotoFragment.class.getSimpleName();
    private Camera mCamera;
    private SurfaceTexture mSurfaceTexture; // mSurfaceTexture must be global to avoid log error spam

    public static PhotoFragment newInstance() {
        Bundle args = new Bundle();
        PhotoFragment fragment = new PhotoFragment();
        fragment.setArguments(args);
        return fragment;
    }

    public PhotoFragment(){}

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        getActivity().setTitle(R.string.photo);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();
        safeCameraOpen();
    }

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        releaseCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_content, container, false);


        Button yo = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.pic);
        yo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                if(mCamera == null){
                    Log.w(LOG_TAG, "@onCreateView mCamera is null!");
                }
                mCamera.takePicture(null, null, mCall);
            }
        });

        Button yoyo = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.vid);
        yoyo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {

            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }

    Camera.PictureCallback mCall = new Camera.PictureCallback() {
        public void onPictureTaken(byte[] data, Camera camera) {
            //decode the data obtained by the camera into a Bitmap and save it

            FileOutputStream outStream = null;
            try {
                String sdCardDirectory = Environment
                        .getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES)
                        .getPath();

                outStream = new FileOutputStream(sdCardDirectory
                        + Utils.getPictureFilename());

                outStream.write(data);
                outStream.close();
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e){
                Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
            } catch (IOException e){
                Log.d("CAMERA", e.getMessage());
            }
            mCamera.startPreview();
        }
    };

    private boolean safeCameraOpen() {
        boolean qOpened = false;
        try {
            releaseCamera();
            mCamera = Camera.open();
            mSurfaceTexture = new SurfaceTexture(Activity.MODE_PRIVATE);
            mCamera.setPreviewTexture(mSurfaceTexture);
            mCamera.startPreview();
            qOpened = (mCamera != null);
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e(LOG_TAG, "failed to open Camera");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return qOpened;
    }

    private void releaseCamera() {
        if (mCamera != null) {
            mCamera.stopPreview();
            mCamera.release();
            mCamera = null;
        }
    }


}
```

Stacktrace:

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                                                                      Process: com.dcs.hiddencamera, PID: 10561
                                                                      java.lang.RuntimeException: takePicture failed
                                                                          at android.hardware.Camera.native_takePicture(Native Method)
                                                                          at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1434)
                                                                          at android.hardware.Camera.takePicture(Camera.java:1379)
                                                                          at com.dcs.hiddencamera.PhotoFragment$1.onClick(PhotoFragment.java:72)
                                                                          at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:5204)
                                                                          at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:21153)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
                                                                          at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
                                                                          at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:148)
                                                                          at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5417)
                                                                          at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:726)
                                                                          at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:616)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Handle runtimeexception in your onClick, also try disabling the button inside onclick and re-enable it after the picture has been saved. The camera apparently cant process two consecutive take picture commands if given too fast. the exception source is inside native camera code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply, how do you suggest enabling/disabling the button? Maybe a global variable?

Comment: yeah go with a instance variable for button.

Comment: I tested it and fixed it. Thanks. It was really simple.